Is the ground screw on this 4" round weatherproof box OK by code?
I recently bought some house brand weatherproof boxes at my local big box store. I'm planning on mounting a lay in lug at the green grounding hole, so bought some longer #10-32 screws to accommodate the thicker lug mounting plate and replace the supplied short green screw.
Sadly, it turns out the supplied green screw and hole are 10-24 threaded, not 10-32! Am I correct in thinking that this is still technically Code compliant because the longer thread engagement distance in this mounting hole makes up for the coarser thread spacing?


UL mark means it was tested to be safe.  Can also search the UL number to make sure it is not fake.  Course thread is a bit harder to strip than fine thread, bigger threads.

Pretty sure the language on screw threads for grounding mentions a number of threads engaged, NOT a specific thread pitch.
Here we go, under NEC 250.8, and the extra one for the UL mark:

Machine screw-type fasteners that engage not less than two threads or are secured with a nut
Thread-forming machine screws that engage not less than two threads in the enclosure
Connections that are part of a listed assembly

The 32 pitch is because most steel boxes are 1/16" thick, so a 32 engages 2 threads, where a 24 pitch would engage only 1-1/2 threads. In a cast aluminum box, there's all sorts of room for thread engagement.
So, yes, it's OK by code.
